# Why are child meta moderators not there in Moderators list?

Tags: discussion, moderators, per-site-meta

Is there a reason why meta moderators are not in the [list of moderators](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators)?

Are the meta moderators for each site the same as moderators for the site? As in Meta moderators for Android Enthusiasts are the same people as moderators for Android Enthusiasts?

This question is not a duplicate because it deals with the all the meta websites and not just meta of Stack Exchange,  as pointed out in the comments below the question.

Comment: @MonicaCellio but the questions are not same? And one can't really guess the content of the answer to that question by just looking at that question?

Comment: Oh you didn't just mean Meta.SE. Sorry, misread.

Comment: I meant both Meta Stack Exchange and other Meta . I saw the question pointed out, but did not guess that the answer was something related to my question. It's ok though

Comment: @MonicaCellio this is not a duplicate

Comment: C Rags, I made an edit to make that clearer and voted to reopen.  (Since the mods on a per-site meta are the same as the main site I don't know what benefit there'd be to a separate listing, but if that's your question then I agree this isn't a dupe.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that moderators are same in the main as well as meta sites, thanks for the edit though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta Stack Exchange is moderated by Stack Exchange staff, and doesn't have dedicated moderators.

Because staff don't appear on the list of moderators, Meta.SE doesn't appear in the list. Also, it'd be odd to have the Meta site in a list of non-Meta SE sites.

Comment: Is there a list of moderators separately for meta sites?

Comment: @Rags Per-site metas are moderated by their site moderators, so the ones you see on that list are the ones moderating respective metas.

Comment: so a user's reputation is the same across a site and it's meta?

Comment: @CRags Yep! They synchronize automatically every couple hours, if I recall. MSE (this site) is an exception in that it has its own reputation.

Comment: This site is an exception since it is 'just' another SE site, without it's own meta ;) .

Answer (score 2):

Per-site metas are moderated by the moderators who moderate the main site. So there is no need to mention those moderators again in the list.

Comare: [Stack Overflow moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) and [Meta Stack Overflow moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators); [Super User moderators](https://superuser.com/users?tab=moderators) and [Meta Super User moderators](http://meta.superuser.com/users?tab=moderators).